# find the exact element clicked in three js whith raycaster and intersects when small parts are closely coupled together to form a complex model

Tags: javascript, three.js

while working on three js. I have a 3d model which has several small parts which are joint together to form a one three d loader (model). now I am using raycaster and intersects for finding out the clicked element. so its basically a door which has small screws, handles, hinges, bolts, rails, rotation points, pivots etc.

My problem is that while using raycaster and three js the element is not getting identified until or unless I zoom. when I zoom into a good extent I am able to identify clicked element. can anyone help me with that where I do get rid of zoom in.

Answer (score 1):

You might be best to create an additional mesh attached/added to the small elements (like screws) - the additional mesh could be defined by a large sphere geometry shape that surrounds the screw. This larger sphere geometry would be invisible (ie its material visibility is false), and would function to intercept raycasting of the small elements like screws that are difficult to intercept on their own.